# Input a string, but the program does not recognize the spaces between words

Tags: python-3.x

I would like this to accept "John Smith" or "Smith, John". Currently this only accepts JohnSmith Smith,John etc. What is the issue?

```
while not str(NAME).isalpha():
            NAME=input("Enter patient's name : ")
        new_entry.append(str(NAME))
```

Comment: Hint: check `' '.isalpha()`

Comment: `NAME` is already a `str`. No need for `str(NAME)`.  It won't accept `Smith,John` either.  Another hint: check `','.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `isalpha` method checks if the string is *one* word, e.g. no numbers and no spaces. For multiple words, you can use something like

```
while not all(s.isalpha() for s in NAME.replace(',', ' ').split()):
```

where the `.replace(',', ' ')` is what allows for treating spaces and commas on the same footing.